# A little confused with Javascript Array.prototype.map() when working with string

Tags: javascript

I'm reading on the map/reduce documentation and this particular string example doesn't make sense to me.

```
var toCode = function(char) {
   return char.charCodeAt(0);    
}
```

First, the thing that works. Why does it work? string is not an array.

```
var text = "Hello World";
var map = Array.prototype.map;
console.log(map.call(text, toCode));
```

Now, the thing that doesn't work. Isn't this exactly the same as above?

```
console.log(text.map(toCode));
```

I use www.codeacademy.com console to test and this is the error message:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '"hello world".map(toCode)')
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second code won't work because strings don't have a `map` method, but you can borrow it from Array, because array methods are meant to work on array-like objects, that is an object with numeric keys, such as strings:

> The map function is intentionally generic; it does not require that
>   its `this` value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to
>   other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the map function
>   can be applied successfully to a host object is
>   implementation-dependent.

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but then the first case working made me think that in Javascript, a string is an array of characters, then the second case must also work. Thanks for clearing.